# Encrypt gnuplot scripts

Tags: gnuplot

I recall when I was using ColdFusion years ago that you could encrypt CF scripts to protect the code and CF could still execute them.

Does any such capacity exist for gnuplot? My guess is it does not.

Answer (score 1):

Gnuplot itself cannot handle encrypted files, but you can use an external tool like `openssl` to encrypt and decrypt your scripts and pipe the decrypted script to gnuplot:

Encrypt:

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -in foobar.gp -out foobar-enc.gp -pass file:foobar.pwd
```

Decrypt and execute gnuplot:

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -d -in foobar-enc.gp -pass file:foobar.pwd | gnuplot
```

Answer (score 0):

That capacity does not exist in gnuplot.